# protect specific url with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a central script 'web' in the root of my site that handles everything. In the .htaccess the following lines tell appache to handle 'web' as a php file:

```
<Files web>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php 
</Files>
```

The script 'web' splits the REQUEST_URI in parts so it can generate the right page: http://www.mysite.com/web/var1/var2/var3 calls 'web' and the script receives var1, var2 and var3.

What i want to do is protect a certain part of the site with .htaccess so that http://www.mysite.com/web/login results in a login-screen. But there is no directory 'login' in which i can put the .htaccess and .htpasswd.

Can this be done?

Comment: this is really strange. You have a login screen but still want a .htaccess to protect that part? Can you give another example?

Comment: why don't you use your `web` script to protect your site?

Comment: I dont have a login page, .htaccess protection would result in one, i mean an authentication box...
Protecting via the web-script is also posible of course, but i was looking for a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

also you can use Location:

```
<Location /path-that-doesnt-exist-in-the-filesystem>
    //your stuff here, for example AuthType Basic, etc...
</Location>
```

Comment: `<Location>` does not work in .htaccess, only in "server config" and "virtual host" context: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location .

Comment: I noticed that, location gives a 500 error when put in .htaccess

Comment: i forgot to mention that it works in the config files only. i think it's preferable though, if you have access to them.